# com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter was found, but is missing another required class

Tags: java, servlets, db2, websphere

I am getting exception pasted below while loading my project urls

Original Exception:

```
Error Message: Filter [LikeMindsFilter]: com.ibm.commerce.likeminds.filter.LikeMindsFilter was found, but is missing another required class.
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: Stores Request Servlet
Error Stack:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/commerce/likeminds/filter/LikeMindsFilter
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance1(Class.java(Compiled Code))
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance1(Class.java(Compiled Code))
     at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java(Compiled Code))
     at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
```

Using WAS 6 and DB2

Comment: its related to websphere right ??

Comment: so where is the connection to DB2 (except that your application connects to db2)? Websphere 6 or websphere 6.1?